# Ubuntu: unable to run script from a program at startup

Tags: ubuntu, startup

In Ubuntu I have a C++ QT program in which I call an external script (.sh).

If I run the program manually (from the command line) everything works fine (the script get called correctly) but if the program get called at the startup (by putting it in `/etc/init.d` and running `update-rc.d`) the program run correctly, but the script doesn't start.

Comment: does your program takes arguments?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it takes an argument that is correctly passed even at startup. I'm doing other tests and I notice that the script is not called even if I create a "desktop launcher". The script get only called if I run the program from the command line.

Comment: Can you add relevant code to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved. The problem was in the script (script1.sh) itself since it used a call to another script (script2.sh): in script1 the call to script2 was done like this "script2". I changed that call to /path/to/script2/script2 and everything works fine.
**The finally question is: why do I need to specify the absolute script path if this was in the environment path ($PATH)?**